# Color filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, filter, filtering

For this [picture](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/617/dsc047751.jpg):
How do I make filter that returns true on brown color (insect) and false on background?

Comment: Steve Eddins' recent article on image processing, "The Two Amigos", may be of interest here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/10/08/the-two-amigos/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose an RGB value that represents brown.  Then for each pixel, calulate e.g. the Euclidean distance in RGB space, and apply a threshold to the result.

RGB may not be the best colour space.

Comment: What is the best color space?

Comment: I have no idea.  Try RGB first.  If that doesn't work, then investigate other colour spaces.